# How to determine in Keycloak JS adapter whether user is logged in with SSO?

Tags: angularjs, single-sign-on, keycloak

To introduce my current setup, I have 3 components:

- Website with some static (CMS) and dynamic parts, a couple of Single Page Applications, everything works on domain `spa.com`.
- REST API, which provides any dynamic functionality (user profile) and is hosted on `api.com` and requires SSO tokens to work.
- SSO server is hosted under `sso.com` domain

I'd like to determine in my SPA whether user has an active SSO session, so when I'm logged in but I do not have tokens, I can:

- do a redirection dance to get tokens
- do not allow user to use registration form

I'm using Keycloak JS adapter, which uses iframe mechanism and checks for `KEYCLOAK_SESSION` cookie and communicates with host window via some flags:

```
var cookie = getCookie('KEYCLOAK_SESSION');
if (cookie) {
    data.loggedIn = true;
    data.session = cookie;
}
```

The problem is that I can not rely on this cookie to check if user is logged in because the cookie has 30 day expiration date, which is way more than an actual Keycloak session lasts, let's say 15 minutes.

This cookie is being set when user gets authenticated and is not refreshed on each token update. I do not understand then it's purpose and the purpose of this flag.

I'm also thinking about relying on local storage and keeping refresh & access token there to determine if user is logged in, either by checking timeout or trying to refresh access token. BUT.. this also is not reliable, because user might have already authenticated using some other application.

To add more context to the problem... one of my SPA applications is a registration wizard, which uses REST API to register user and receives `login_hint` in return. This `login_hint` can be used as a wildcard in SSO redirect to pass the challenge and log in immediately.

However, if some other user is already logged in, we get in return session of this other user, not the one that should be logged in because of used `login_hint`.

Comment: `This cookie is being set when user gets authenticated and is not refreshed on each token update. I do not understand then it's purpose and the purpose of this flag.` Dude! I am in the exact same boat - what the heck is the purpose of the cookie in the iframe? The adapter polls the iframe to check status every 5 seconds, but it's just parsing the same cookie over and over again - it makes no sense? Whenever I log the user out via the admin console in a separate window, no callbacks get fired, the current implementation of the iframe is useless (I must be missing something?)

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Is that cookie's only purpose to be used by that iframe to check when it expires, so that we know it in the javascript? I want to know when the user got logged out on Keycloak too.

Comment: That cookie _is_ the Keycloak session cookie. Say the user opens your app in 5 tabs, then logs out in one of the tabs, the cookie will be removed when that tab redirects to the keycloak domain. Since the cookie is removed, the other 4 tabs will then notice that fact the next time they loop through. Thus, those 4 tabs will detect the logout in the 5th tab, enabling them to render something like "You have been logged out."

Comment: Here's some doc about it: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#CreatingUpdatingSessions